# How to create a Global image using QML?

Tags: image, qt, global-variables, qml, qobject

Currently developing a QML project with a set of images, I am currently using the function:

```
                function imageDeselection()
                {
                    imageSelect.visible = false
                    imageInitial.visible = true
                }
```

This function toggles between the photos although cannot get global scope when trying to use this function later in the code as the images are not declared. Has anybody had success in allowing the images in QML to have a global scope? Thanks in advance Blair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your root QML element (usually `ApplicationWindow`) create a

```
property Image globalImage : someImage
```

Then `globalImage` will be accessible from everywhere because of QML's dynamic scope.